# MySql on update trigger. Error of DELIMITER

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to create trigger in MySql but get the following error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER library_update
AFTER UPDATE ON wq6vt_vehiclemanager_vehicles
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT IGNORE INTO wq6vt_vehiclemanager_library (maker, model) VALUES(NEW.maker, NEW.vmodel);

    INSERT INTO wq6vt_vehiclemanager_library_data (co2_class) 
      SELECT co2_class FROM wq6vt_vehiclemanager_vehicles
      WHERE maker = NEW.maker AND vmodel = NEW.vmodel;   
END $$
DELIMITER;
```

The first query in the trigger do not lead to errors, but second one does. There is some problem with SELECT inside of INSERT ...I think so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there should be a space between the keyword and the symbol,

```
DELIMITER ;
      -- ^  space in between here
```